# Post Photos to Facebook Album in Order without moving album cover

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

I'm using https://github.com/arsduo/koala to post photos to Facebook albums. The photos maintain a rough ordering based on the order that the photos are posted, except for the beginning of the album.

Every group of photos that is posted has a few that will move the album covers and post photos at the beginning of the album, rather than at the end in order of photos posted.

I need a solid way of posting photos to Facebook albums where the photos are posted at the end of all the existing photos in the album and do not move the photos at the beginning of the album. There must be some setting to post the photo at the end rather than the beginning. `position` is deprecated, but seems to be what I want here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get the order to be correct was to post the photos slowly (7-8 seconds between each photo uploaded)